# If..else conditions error within switch case and can't retrieve the previous selected value

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement, conditional-statements

HTML

```
<tr>
  <td>Asset Group:</td>
  <td>
    <select id="assetgroupSelect" name='assetgroupSelect' onChange="Togglefields(this)">
      <option value=""+>(choose asset group)</option>
                                    <?while ($arrResult = $result->Fetch()){?>
      <option value = "<? echo $arrResult['Group_ID']?>,<? echo $arrResult['Asset_Type_ID']?>"> <? echo $arrResult['Group_Name'] ?> </option><?}?>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr id='remarkhiddenRow'>
  <td>Remarks: </label>
  </td>
  <td><input type="text" id="remark"></td>
</tr>

<tr id='filehiddenRow'>
  <td>Supporting File: </label>
  </td>
  <td><input type="text" id="file"></td>
</tr>
<trid='contacthiddenRow'>
  <td>Contact No: </td>
  <td><input type="text" id="contactNo"></td>
  </tr>


  <tr id='emailhiddenRow'>
    <td>Email: </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="email"></td>
  </tr>
```

JS

```
function Togglefields(obj) {
  var value = "call the value from dropdown selected";
  var namevalue = "call the namefrom dropdown selected";

  var assettypeid = "call the secondvalue from dropdown selected";

  switch (assettypeid) {
    case '9':
      alert(namevalue);
      if (namevalue == "Rack" || namevalue == "VLAN" || namevalue == "Cluster Segment") {
        $('#remarkhiddenRow').show();
        $('#filehiddenRow').show();
      } else if (namevalue == "Vendor") {
        $('#receiveddatehiddenRow').show();
        $('#remarkhiddenRow').show();
        $('#filehiddenRow').show();
        $('#contacthiddenRow').show();
        $('#emailhiddenRow').show();
        $('#supporthiddenRow').show();
      } else {
        $('#remarkhiddenRow').show();
        $('#filehiddenRow').show();
        $('#contacthiddenRow').show();
        $('#emailhiddenRow').show();

      }
      break;
    default:
      $('#receiveddatehiddenRow').hide();
      $("#remarkhiddenRow").hide();
      $('#filehiddenRow').hide();
      $('#contacthiddenRow').hide();
      $('#emailhiddenRow').hide();
      $('#supporthiddenRow').hide();
  }
}
```

textbox fields are hide already before selecting dropdown list.I have dropdown list and when select the dropdwon list value (9) if the name is equal with "Rack" I showed up two textboxes, but when I selected "Vendor" it showed six textboxes. However, when I selected back to "Rack" there were also showing six textboxes instead of showing two textboxes. How should I need to do for that case ? Anyone suggest me please !! Thank you.

Comment: Please supply all your code(HTML and Javascript together)

Comment: The code for `Rack` needs to hide all the other textboxes.

Comment: I suggest you give all the checkboxes the same class. Then you can do `$(".class").hide();` to hide them all at once, then show the ones you want to show depending on what was selected from the dropdown.

Comment: You can try something like **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/b3dt6dpL/)**

Comment: @Rajesh thanks ! its very useful

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the suggestion. its work !!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide the elements you don't want to show and be more specific in your conditions. Like this:

```
switch(assettypeid)

           {
               case '9':
               alert (namevalue);
                    if (namevalue =="Rack" || namevalue== "VLAN" || namevalue=="Cluster Segment"){
                        $('#remarkhiddenRow').show();
                        $('#filehiddenRow').show();

                        }
                    else {

                        $('#filehiddenRow').hide();
                        $('#contacthiddenRow').hide();
                        $('#emailhiddenRow').hide();
                        $('#supporthiddenRow').hide();

                    }

                    if (namevalue=="Vendor"){
                        $('#receiveddatehiddenRow').show();
                        $('#remarkhiddenRow').show();
                        $('#filehiddenRow').show();
                        $('#contacthiddenRow').show();
                        $('#emailhiddenRow').show();
                        $('#supporthiddenRow').show();

                        }

                    if (namevalue != "Rack" && namevalue != "VLAN" && namevalue != "Cluster Segment" && namevalue != "Vendor") {                          
                        $('#remarkhiddenRow').show();
                        $('#filehiddenRow').show();
                        $('#contacthiddenRow').show();
                        $('#emailhiddenRow').show();

                        }
                    else {                          
                        $('#receiveddatehiddenRow').hide();
                        $('#supporthiddenRow').hide();
                    }


                        break;

                default:
                        $('#receiveddatehiddenRow').hide();
                        $("#remarkhiddenRow").hide();
                        $('#filehiddenRow').hide();
                        $('#contacthiddenRow').hide();
                        $('#emailhiddenRow').hide();
                        $('#supporthiddenRow').hide();

           }
```